# How to put the url on string.xml in android?

Tags: android, string

I store the url in string like this

```
 <string name="selfie_smile" formatted="false" >http://hksevens.cathaypacific.com/en/smile?utm_source=mobile_app_android&utm_medium=internal&utm_content=smile&utm_campaign=HK7s</string>
```

This will output the %26 instead of & in my browser

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.event_win)));

startActivity(browserIntent);
```

And also the same when I post to facebook , what should I change to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing & with **&amp;**
The reason is that it will think everything past the ampersand is an ampersand character code.